# Fumes mechanics for Acid Elementals

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The Fumes ability for the [Acic Elemental](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/quasi-elemental-acid/acid-quasi-elemental-elder) reads;

> The fumes from an acid quasi-elemental's body act as an inhaled poison. Creatures within 5 ft. of an acid quasi-elemental must make succeed on a DC 20 Fortitude save or take 1 point of Constitution damage each round. This poison does not have a frequency; a creature is safe as soon as it moves more than 5 ft. away from the acid quasi-elemental.

I see three possible interpretations:

A - When a character enters the area within 5ft of the elemental, he makes a Fortitude save. If he fails, he starts taking 1pt of Constitution damage per round.

B - As long as a character is within 5ft of the elemental, he has to make a Fortitude save each round. If he fails, he immediately takes 1pt of Constitution damage.

C - As long as a character is within 5ft of the elemental, he has to make a Fortitude save each round. If he fails, he starts taking 1pt of Constitution damage per round.

C seems unlikely, but A and B both seems equally right to me. Which is the correct interpretation?

Comment: I agree; A and B seem equally-reasonable to me. *Sigh.*

Comment: @KRyan Yeah, that *each round* phrase is totally in the wrong place. It should be be at the sentence's *beginning* not *ending.*

Comment: [rant]Everything about this ability is badly written. The authors say "it's a poison", then remove all the poison-related rules, rather than just appending "This is a poison effect." at the end. Even then, why would that even be a poison effect rather than acid?[/rant]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## It *Probably* Should Be B

The [acid quasi-elemental](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/quasi-elemental-acid)'s extraordinary ability fumes says that

> The fumes from an acid quasi-elemental's body act as an inhaled poison. Creatures within 5 ft. of an acid quasi-elemental must make succeed [*sic*] on a DC 10 Fortitude save or take 1 point of Constitution damage each round. This poison does not have a frequency; a creature is safe as soon as it moves more than 5 ft. away from the acid quasi-elemental.
>
> **(This is what it says.)**

It's pretty clear this could've used another editorial pass. Were I the editor of the [*Tome of Horrors Complete*](http://shop.d20pfsrd.com/collections/frog-god-games/products/pf-the-tome-of-horrors-complete), I might've good-naturedly pointed out to the author that what's written says that

> A creature that is within 5 ft. of an acid quasi-elemental must make a Fortitude save (DC 10). Failure means the creature suffers 1 point of Constitution damage each round forever and ever and even after that. *The creature failed a Fort save!* That creature sucks fumes and dies for eternity, the loser.
>
> **(This is what *that* means.)**

Then I'd point out that the ability seems a bit much for a CR 1 [Small acid quasi-elemental](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/quasi-elemental-acid/acid-quasi-elemental-small) and recommend that perhaps a better way to put this would be that

> A creature ending its turn adjacent to an acid quasi-elemental makes a Fortitude save *versus* poison (DC 10). Failure means that creature suffers 1 point of Constitution damage.
>
> **(This is *probably* what it *should* say.)**

Luckily, the special ability fumes provides enough information that we can almost get to the revision I propose when it says there's *no* frequency, and, without the ability saying this is *ongoing* damage, this damage is a one-time effect but occurring each time a creature is within 5 ft. of an acid quasi-elemental.

The ability *is* contingent upon the *other* creature not the acid quasi-elemental, so this ability is checked when the other creature moves or stays within 5 ft. of the quasi-elemental (the DM chooses whether to have the creature make the saving throw at the ending or the beginning of the creature's turn; I suggest the ending) *not* when the quasi-elemental gets within 5 ft. of another creature.

Were the Constitution damage ongoing (i.e. as per your options A and C, with the character *starting* to take Constitution damage), the lack of a method for *ending* the ongoing Constitution damage would make even a single [Small acid quasi-elemental](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/elemental/quasi-elemental-acid/acid-quasi-elemental-small) an *eventual* deathtrap for the vast majority of creatures, making it far more dangerous than its CR 1 would suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Important to note: You can [hold your breath](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/environment.html#suffocation) against an inhaled poison. One of the few reasons archetypes like [Internal Alchemist](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spellcastingClassOptions/alchemist.html#internal-alchemist-(archetype)) are awesome.

How inhaled poisons work:

> Inhaled: These poisons are delivered the moment a creature enters an
>   area containing such poisons and do not usually have an onset time.
>   For most inhaled poisons, 1 dose fills a volume equal to a 10-foot
>   cube. **A creature can attempt to hold its breath while inside the area
>   to avoid inhaling the toxin.** A creature holding its breath receives a
>   50% chance of not having to make a Fortitude save each round. See the
>   rules for holding your breath and suffocation. If a creature is
>   holding its breath and fails the constitution check to continue doing
>   so, rather than suffocating it begins to breathe normally again (and
>   is subject to the effects of the inhaled poison if still in the area).
>   [Source](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateEquipment/gear/poisons.html#poisons)

So how it would play out would be:

> B - As long as a character is within 5ft of the elemental, he has to
>   make a Fortitude save each round ***provided they arent holding their
>   breath. If they are, there is only a 50% chance that they have to make
>   a fortitude save.*** If he fails the fortitude save, he immediately takes 1pt of
>   Constitution damage.

Also, poison immunity and the monster ability [No breath](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/additionalMonsters/universalMonsterRules.html#no-breath) would ignore the fortitude checks as well, for obvious reasons.